# Should we allow questions asking release date of anime or manga?

Tags: discussion

If a persons likes to know the release dates of a particular anime or manga episode, or like if someone is asking when is the new season of a particular anime releasing.

Questions like these should they be allowed?

Comment: It already is, unless it has not been announced, in which its off topic.

Comment: oh thanks... i tried searching for a similar question before posting but couldnt find the duplicate because i asked differently